# Can Newtonsoft.Json dll of multiple versions co-exist?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, dll

We have 2 independent projects (**A** and **B**) that reference

```
Newtonsoft.Json dll.
```

Project **A** uses the version 6.0.0.0 while the Project **B** uses the version 10.0.0.0

Now when I try to reference the dll from Project B (to apply the service which involves de-serialization), it throws the Exception

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0,...
```

[image]

I understand this is basically version conflicts. One of the solutions is to update the version from the Project **A**.

However, assume that I won't pick this approach (fear that it could break dependency or any unknown error), can I solve this by making them co-exist?

Comment: Give each a unique strong name.  Otherwise you'll need to isolate the other code in a separate AppDomain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add Runtime AssemblyBinding in ProjectB and redirect both versions to 10v.

In the app.config

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-10.0.0.0" newVersion="10.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: wouldn't Project A need the redirect? B is already wanting to use this version

Comment: @jeremy: The assemblyBinding bindingRedirect is only required on the project that is running / loading the assemblies. Project A does not require the redirect since it is not executing by itself - if it were, it would just use v6; project B does because when it executed it has code requiring 2 diferent versions of the json lib (itself and the refed assembly); 
The runtime can only load one to so it needs to choose one. The redirect explicity tells the runtime to load v10, anytime it finds a need for a version between 0 and 10)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `<HintPath>` in .csproj file point to appropriate dll

Usually I'm working of solution with multiple projects in it, and different dll
No problem. Maybe you could try new blank solution to check.

[Start blank solution, add 2 new projects, install each with different version using nuget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRrT9.jpg)

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ProjectA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object product = new
            {
                Name = "Apple",
                Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28),
                Sizes = new string[] {"Small"}
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("Newtonsoft.Json.dll");
            Console.WriteLine($"Using version {assembly.GetName().Version}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Serialize just fine: {json}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjBsh.jpg)